# Concatenating multiple data dictionaries in python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, data-dictionary

I have created multiple data dictionaries with `year_quarter` key. Then I used `.describe()` on one of the columns I was interested to study, column `A`. Now I want to create a `DataFrame` with the statistics created with `.describe()`.
This is what I did:

```
H_cltn = {} #original data dictionaries
stat_cltn = {} 

QY =['2013_1', '2013_2', '2013_3', '2013_4']

for item in QY:
    stat_cltn[item] = H_cltn[item]['A'].describe()

df = pd.DataFrame(['count','mean','std','min','25%','50%','75%','max'])
for item in QY:
    df[item] = pd.Series(stat_cltn[item])
```

But this gives me `NaN` values for the whole table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to simplify along these lines:

```
QY =['2013_1', '2013_2', '2013_3', '2013_4']
df = pd.DataFrame()
for item in QY:
    df = pd.concat([df, H_cltn[item]['A'].describe()], axis=1) ## possibly axis=0
```